# Click event occurs only on text of the QPushButton

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

In Qt Designer I created a simple app with a button with these style sheets:
[image: style sheets].

```
QPushButton {
    outline:0;
    background: #434343;
    color: #fff;
    padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
QPushButton:hover:!pressed{
    background-color: rgb(115, 115, 115);
    border:1px solid white;
}
```

With these style sheets in order to click on the button, I have to click exactly on the text of it to work correctly and anywhere around the text wouldn't emit clicked signal.
This is while we don't have this problem with a button without any style sheet.

The output of Qt designer using pyuic5 command:
and I'm running this code on Windows 10

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(351, 271)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 20, 91, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(11, 118, 225, 78))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                        "    outline:0;\n"
                                        "    background: #434343;\n"
                                        "    color: #fff;\n"
                                        "    padding:30;\n"
                                        "    border-radius: 5px;\n"
                                        "}\n"
                                        "QPushButton:hover:!pressed{\n"
                                        "    background-color: rgb(115, 115, 115);\n"
                                        "    border:1px solid white;\n"
                                        "}\n"
                                        "")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 351, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.click)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.click2)


    def click(self):
        print("click")

    def click2(self):
        print("click2")

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Please state the platform you are on, the exact version of Qt you are using, and also provide a [mcve].

Comment: @ekhumoro sorry about that. I added my code to the question.

Comment: It looks like a windows-specifc problem, since I can't reproduce it on linux. Try setting an explict border in the first style rule. Does that make any difference? If not, try removing the css properties one by one until you find the one which causes the issue.

Comment: I can't reproduce it on Windows 7

Comment: @Mohammad Did you make any progress with this?

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes, there was a problem with padding. I removed it and it was fixed.